BIND slave does not acknowledge notifies from master
I can't get BIND slave to accept notifies from master.
Master's log says that notifies are being sent:
05-Nov-2024 11:56:42.655 general: info: zone example_zone.eu/IN/internal-view: loaded serial 2015010160
05-Nov-2024 11:56:42.655 general: info: zone example_zone.eu/IN/external-view: loaded serial 2015011450
05-Nov-2024 11:56:42.659 notify: info: zone example_zone.eu/IN/external-view: sending notifies (serial 2015011450)


1.2.3.4 - IP address of BIND master
6.7.8.9 - IP address of BIND slave
Master's named.conf.options:
server 0.0.0.0/0 {
    edns no;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";


    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
    };
    
    dnssec-validation no;
    dnssec-enable no;

    notify yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035

    version "12345";

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on { any; };

    recursion no;
    
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-notify { internal-acl; 6.7.8.9; };
    allow-query-cache { internal-acl; };
    allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1;  6.7.8.9; };

};

acl internal-acl {
    127.0.0.0/8;
    10.0.0.0/8;
};


// INTERNAL
view "internal-view" {

    match-clients { 
        127.0.0.0/8;
        !10.6.1.251;
        10.0.0.0/8;
   }; 
   // internal-acl; };

    recursion yes;

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

    zone "expo" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward/expo.dns";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query { 
            !10.6.1.251;
            127.0.0.0/8;
            10.0.0.0/8;
        };
        /*allow-query { any; };*/
    };

    zone "example_zone.eu" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward/internal.example_zone.eu.dns";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query { any; };
    };

    zone "10.in-addr.arpa" { 
        type master;
        notify no;
        allow-query { 
            127.0.0.0/8;
            10.0.0.0/8;
        };
        allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; };
        file "/etc/bind/reverse/10"; 
    };

};


// EXTERNAL
view "external-view" {

    match-clients { any; };
    recursion no;

    //zone "." { type hint; file "/etc/bind/root.hints"; };

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";



    zone "16.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "17.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "18.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "19.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "20.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "21.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "22.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "23.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "24.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "25.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "26.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "27.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "28.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "29.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "30.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };
    zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };

    zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/bind/reverse/empty"; };


    zone "example_zone.eu"
    {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/forward/example_zone.eu.dns";
      allow-transfer {  6.7.8.9; };
    };


};

Slave's named.conf.options :
logging {
        channel log_general {
                file "/var/log/named/named_general.log";
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
        severity debug;
        };

        channel log_xfer {
                file "/var/log/named/xfer.log";
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                severity debug;
        };

        category lame-servers { null; };
        category xfer-out { log_xfer; };
        category xfer-in  { log_xfer; };
        category general  { log_general; };
        category client   { log_general; };
        category config   { log_general; };
        category update   { log_general; };
        category update-security   { log_general; };
        category default  { log_general; };
};


zone "example_zone.eu"
{
  type slave;
  masters { 1.2.3.4; };
  file "example_zone.eu.dns";
  allow-transfer {  1.2.3.4; };
  allow-notify {  1.2.3.4; };
};

Slave's log is empty, nothing happens there whatsoever.
I have of course increased serial in forward zone file and restarted master.
How can get slave to accept notifies?
Version of BIND9 on master and slave:
ii  bind9                          1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u11     amd64        Internet Domain Name Server


Is the slave  allowed and capable of to doing a zone transfer (IIRC dig -t AXFR example_zone.eu @1.2.3.4) ? Is the firewall open for both  UDP port 53 AND TCP 53? Is the slave even starting properly?
